# UPC shared arrays

Tags: c++, c, upc

I want to declare a shared matrix in the global address space but not to perform any calculations by the UPC threads, but the GPU using CUDA.

So is it possible to declare a UPC shared array in which the number elements in the array is NOT equal or a multiply of the number of threads (THREADS variable) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the number of threads at the compile time using upcc flags. For more information on upcc flags check [upcc man page.](http://upc.lbl.gov/docs/user/upcc.html)